# Minecraft launcher not logging in on windows PC and not updating on a mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc

I own a macbook, a mac and a windows PC. I generally use my MacBook for gaming (weird, I know) but I recently met some restrictions forcing me to use a different device for gaming. I had used the windows PC before for minecraft, but I got logged out some time ago and I can't get back in (via the minecraft launcher). It used to say it could not connect but now it just says it is an incorrect username/email and/or password. I have checked my minecraft password on the website (minecraft.net) and it works just fine on there but I just can't get in on the launcher. I also cannot access minecraft on my mac because "the launcher is unable to update". The circumstances basically are that I can't play minecraft at all at the moment so I would appreciate help.

Comment: Welcome to arqade. I'm afraid the community here won't be able to help with this specific issue; you're best off contacting Mojang support on this one.

Answer (score 0):

### This is what you should try:

1. Make sure you are using a **legitimate** copy of Minecraft.  People can run into problems like these if they are trying to use an unauthorized or cracked copy of Minecraft.
2. **Restart your Minecraft**.  Sometimes if Minecraft is left open for long periods of time it can self-log itself off and require you to re-type your username and password to get back on.  However, it doesn't always let you  (This may be a bug, I have had this happen to me).  Just restart your Minecraft and it may let you log in.
3. **Wait**.  Sometime Minecraft servers can be having trouble and you just need to wait them out.
4. Try **restarting your computer**.  I'm unsure of the reason for this, but one time I was about to contact Mojang because my info was no longer working, I restarted my PC and all was well.
5. Lastly, try to **uninstall** and re-install Minecraft.  This is the last resort and solves many related problems involved with Minecraft.

If all of these fail then you should try contacting Mojang.  You can also visit https://help.mojang.com/ were you might find specific troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the password to log in but it says it's incorrect, it's because the account could be hacked.

Answer (score -1):

Like Jason_ said, try to uninstall and reinstall Minecraft, but make a copy and move it to a USB before you uninstall it. Remove the USB and uninstall. Then add the USB into the port. Finally, remove the one from the USB and try again.